# Thymeleaf: Empty List doesn't show input fields

Tags: thymeleaf

I'm trying to create a html "Edit/New" page to edit or add new a publisher. One of the details would be an ArrayList of subPublishers. Although the ArrayList might be empty if the publisher has no subPublishers or if i add new publisher.

My issue is with the input fields. I'm attempting to show the ArrayList as follows...

```
<form id="publisherForm" th:object="${publisherForm}" th:action="@{/publishers/publishers-edit/}" method="post" class="form-horizontal">
    <input type="hidden" th:field="*{id}" />
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6 b-r">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Publisher name: </label>
                <div class="col-sm-9">
                    <input th:field="*{publisherName}" type="text" class="form-control" th:maxlength="45"/>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Description: </label>
                <div class="col-sm-9">
                    <input th:field="*{description}" type="text" class="form-control" th:maxlength="200"/>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Enabled: </label>
                <div class="col-sm-9">
                    <input th:field="*{status}" value="ENABLED" type="checkbox"/>  
                </div>
             </div>
             <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Website URL: </label>
                <div class="col-sm-9">
                    <input th:field="*{websiteURL}" type="text" class="form-control" th:maxlength="50"/>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Subpublishers: </label>
                <div class="col-sm-9">                                                              
                    <div class="table-responsive">
                        <table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
                            <thead>
                                <th>
                                    <button class="btn btn-white" type="submit" name="addRow">+</button>
                                </th>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                                <tr th:each="subPublisher,stat : *{subPublishers}">
                                    <td>
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" th:field="*{subPublishers[__${stat.index}__].name}" />
                                    </td>
                                    <td>

                                        <button class="btn btn-white" type="submit" name="removeRow" th:value="${stat.index}">-</button>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>                                      
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6">  
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-sm-9 col-sm-offset-3">
                    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Save</button>                                                 
                    <a class="btn btn-white" th:href="@{/publishers}">Cancel</a>                                                 
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

**Controller**

```
   @MenuController(value = "/publisher", item = Item.Publishers)
public class PublisherController {

    private PublisherService publisherService;
    private PublisherConverter publisherConverter;
    private SubPublisherConverter subPublisherConverter;

    public PublisherController(PublisherService publisherService, PublisherConverter publisherConverter, SubPublisherConverter subPublisherConverter) {
        this.publisherService = publisherService;
        this.publisherConverter = publisherConverter;
        this.subPublisherConverter = subPublisherConverter;
    }

    @GetMapping
    public String newPublisher( Model model) {

        PublisherResource publisher = new PublisherResource();
        publisher.setStatus(true);
        publisher.setSubPublishers(new ArrayList<SubPublisherResource>());

        return showPage(publisher, model);
    }

    protected String showPage(PublisherResource publisher, Model model) {

        model.addAttribute("publisherForm", publisher);

        return "publishers/publishers-edit";
    }

    @PostMapping
    public String createPublisher(@ModelAttribute("publisherForm") @Validated PublisherResource resource, BindingResult result, Model model) {
        if (result.hasErrors()) {
            return showPage(resource, model);
        }
        return savePublisher(0, resource);
    }

    @GetMapping("/{publisherId}")
    public String editPublisher(@PathVariable int publisherId, Model model) {

        Publisher publisher = publisherService.getPublisher(publisherId);
        PublisherResource res = publisherConverter.convert(publisher);
        res.setSubPublishers(publisherService.getSubPublishers(publisher).stream()
                .map(s -> subPublisherConverter.convert(s))
                .collect(Collectors.toList())
                );

        return showPage(res, model);
    }


    @PostMapping("/{publisherId}")
    public String updatePublisher(@PathVariable int publisherId, @ModelAttribute("publisherForm") @Validated PublisherResource resource, BindingResult result, Model model) {
        if (result.hasErrors()) {
            return showPage(resource, model);
        }
        return savePublisher(publisherId, resource);
    }

    protected String savePublisher(int publisherId, PublisherResource resource) {
        Publisher publisher = populatePublisher(publisherId, resource);
        List<SubPublisher> subPublishers = populateSubPublishers(resource);

        if (publisherId == 0) {
            publisherService.createPublisher(publisher, subPublishers);
        } else {
            publisherService.updatePublisher(publisher, subPublishers);
        }

        return "redirect:/publishers";
    }

    protected Publisher populatePublisher(int publisherId, PublisherResource resource) {
        Publisher publisher = null;
        if (publisherId == 0) {
            publisher = new Publisher();
            publisher.setTimeAdded(new Date());
        } else {
            publisher = publisherService.getPublisher(publisherId);
        }

        publisher.setPublisherName(resource.getPublisherName());
        publisher.setDescription(resource.getDescription());
        publisher.setStatus(resource.isStatus());
        publisher.setWebsiteURL(resource.getWebsiteURL());

        return publisher;
    }

    protected List<SubPublisher> populateSubPublishers(PublisherResource resource){
        if(resource.getSubPublishers() != null){
            return resource.getSubPublishers().stream()
                    .map(s -> {
                        SubPublisher subPublisher = new SubPublisher();
                        subPublisher.setName(s.getName());
                        return subPublisher;
                    })
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
        }
        return Collections.emptyList();
    }

    @PostMapping(params={"addRow"})
    public String addRow(final PublisherResource publisher, final BindingResult bindingResult, Model model) {
        publisher.getSubPublishers().add(new SubPublisherResource());
        return showPage(publisher, model);
    }

    @PostMapping(params={"removeRow"})
    public String removeRow(final PublisherResource publisher, final BindingResult bindingResult, 
            final HttpServletRequest req, Model model) {
        final Integer rowId = Integer.valueOf(req.getParameter("removeRow"));
        publisher.getSubPublishers().remove(rowId.intValue());
        return showPage(publisher, model);
    }
}
```

**PublisherResource**

```
    public class PublisherResource {

    private int id;
    private String publisherName;
    private String description;
    private boolean status;
    private String websiteURL;
    private List<SubPublisherResource> subPublishers = new ArrayList<>();

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getPublisherName() {
        return publisherName;
    }
    public void setPublisherName(String publisherName) {
        this.publisherName = publisherName;
    }
    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }
    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }
    public boolean isStatus() {
        return status;
    }
    public void setStatus(boolean status) {
        this.status = status;
    }
    public String getWebsiteURL() {
        return websiteURL;
    }
    public void setWebsiteURL(String websiteURL) {
        this.websiteURL = websiteURL;
    }
    public List<SubPublisherResource> getSubPublishers() {
        return subPublishers;
    }
    public void setSubPublishers(List<SubPublisherResource> subPublishers) {
        this.subPublishers = subPublishers;
    }
}
```

I use exampel from thymeleaf documentation http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/thymeleafspring.html#dynamic-fields

The problem is that when the ArrayList is empty, the input fields do not show on the page! Also when edit publisher that have subpublishers, if i remove all of them i lose input fields and I can't add any other subpublishers.  Which pretty much makes it impossible to add an subpublishers.

How is this handled with Thymeleaf?

**Update Controller**

```
@MenuController(value = "/publisher", item = Item.Publishers)
public class PublisherController {

    private PublisherResource publisherResource;
    private PublisherService publisherService;
    private PublisherConverter publisherConverter;
    private SubPublisherConverter subPublisherConverter;


    public PublisherController(PublisherResource publisherResource, PublisherService publisherService,
            PublisherConverter publisherConverter, SubPublisherConverter subPublisherConverter) {
        this.publisherResource = publisherResource;
        this.publisherService = publisherService;
        this.publisherConverter = publisherConverter;
        this.subPublisherConverter = subPublisherConverter;
    }

    @GetMapping
    public String newPublisher( Model model) {

        PublisherResource publisher = new PublisherResource();
        publisher.setStatus(true);
        publisher.setSubPublishers(new ArrayList<SubPublisherResource>());

        return showPage(publisher, model);
    }

    protected String showPage(PublisherResource publisher, Model model) {

        model.addAttribute("publisherForm", publisher);

        return "publishers/publishers-edit";
    }

    @PostMapping
    public String createPublisher(@ModelAttribute("publisherForm") @Validated PublisherResource resource, BindingResult result, Model model) {
        if (result.hasErrors()) {
            return showPage(resource, model);
        }
        return savePublisher(0, resource);
    }

    @GetMapping
    public String editPublisher(Model model) {

        Publisher publisher = publisherService.getPublisher(publisherResource.getId());
        PublisherResource res = publisherConverter.convert(publisher);
        res.setSubPublishers(publisherService.getSubPublishers(publisher).stream()
                .map(s -> subPublisherConverter.convert(s))
                .collect(Collectors.toList())
                );

        return showPage(res, model);
    }


    @PostMapping
    public String updatePublisher( @ModelAttribute("publisherForm") @Validated PublisherResource resource, BindingResult result, Model model) {
        if (result.hasErrors()) {
            return showPage(resource, model);
        }
        return savePublisher(publisherResource.getId(), resource);
    }

    protected String savePublisher(int publisherId, PublisherResource resource) {
        Publisher publisher = populatePublisher(publisherId, resource);
        List<SubPublisher> subPublishers = populateSubPublishers(resource);

        if (publisherId == 0) {
            publisherService.createPublisher(publisher, subPublishers);
        } else {
            publisherService.updatePublisher(publisher, subPublishers);
        }

        return "redirect:/publishers";
    }

    protected Publisher populatePublisher(int publisherId, PublisherResource resource) {
        Publisher publisher = null;
        if (publisherId == 0) {
            publisher = new Publisher();
            publisher.setTimeAdded(new Date());
        } else {
            publisher = publisherService.getPublisher(publisherId);
        }

        publisher.setPublisherName(resource.getPublisherName());
        publisher.setDescription(resource.getDescription());
        publisher.setStatus(resource.isStatus());
        publisher.setWebsiteURL(resource.getWebsiteURL());

        return publisher;
    }

    protected List<SubPublisher> populateSubPublishers(PublisherResource resource){
        if(resource.getSubPublishers() != null){
            return resource.getSubPublishers().stream()
                    .map(s -> {
                        SubPublisher subPublisher = new SubPublisher();
                        subPublisher.setName(s.getName());
                        return subPublisher;
                    })
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
        }
        return Collections.emptyList();
    }

    @PostMapping(params={"addRow"})
    public String addRow(final PublisherResource publisher, final BindingResult bindingResult, Model model) {
        publisher.getSubPublishers().add(new SubPublisherResource());
        return showPage(publisher, model);
    }

    @PostMapping(params={"removeRow"})
    public String removeRow(final PublisherResource publisher, final BindingResult bindingResult, 
            final HttpServletRequest req, Model model) {
        final Integer rowId = Integer.valueOf(req.getParameter("removeRow"));
        publisher.getSubPublishers().remove(rowId.intValue());
        return showPage(publisher, model);
    }
}
```

**Update 2 - all code:**

**Entities Publisher and SubPublisher:**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "publisher")
public class Publisher {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String publisherName;

    @Column(name = "description")
    private String description;

    @Column(name = "status")
    private boolean status;

    @Column(name = "website_url")
    private String websiteURL;

    @Column(name = "time_added") 
    private Date timeAdded;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getPublisherName() {
        return publisherName;
    }

    public void setPublisherName(String publisherName) {
        this.publisherName = publisherName;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public boolean isStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(boolean status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    public String getWebsiteURL() {
        return websiteURL;
    }

    public void setWebsiteURL(String websiteURL) {
        this.websiteURL = websiteURL;
    }

    public Date getTimeAdded() {
        return timeAdded;
    }

    public void setTimeAdded(Date timeAdded) {
        this.timeAdded = timeAdded;
    }
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "sub_publisher")
public class SubPublisher {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private int id;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "publisher_id")
    private Publisher publisher;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Publisher getPublisher() {
        return publisher;
    }

    public void setPublisher(Publisher publisher) {
        this.publisher = publisher;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

**Repositories**

```
public interface PublisherRepository extends JpaDataTableRepository<Publisher, Integer> {

    public Publisher findById(int id);
}

public interface SubPublisherRepository extends JpaRepository<SubPublisher, Integer> {

    List<SubPublisher> findByPublisher(Publisher publisher);
    void deleteByPublisher(Publisher publisher);
}
```

**PublisherResource**

```
public class PublisherResource {

    private int id;
    private String publisherName;
    private String description;
    private boolean status;
    private String websiteURL;
    private List<SubPublisherResource> subPublishers = new ArrayList<>();

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getPublisherName() {
        return publisherName;
    }
    public void setPublisherName(String publisherName) {
        this.publisherName = publisherName;
    }
    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }
    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }
    public boolean isStatus() {
        return status;
    }
    public void setStatus(boolean status) {
        this.status = status;
    }
    public String getWebsiteURL() {
        return websiteURL;
    }
    public void setWebsiteURL(String websiteURL) {
        this.websiteURL = websiteURL;
    }
    public List<SubPublisherResource> getSubPublishers() {
        return subPublishers;
    }
    public void setSubPublishers(List<SubPublisherResource> subPublishers) {
        this.subPublishers = subPublishers;
    }
}
```

**SubPublisherResource**

```
public class SubPublisherResource {

    private String name;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

**PublisherController**

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/publisher")
public class PublisherController {

    private PublisherService publisherService;
    private PublisherConverter publisherConverter;
    private SubPublisherConverter subPublisherConverter;

    @Autowired
    public PublisherController(PublisherService publisherService, PublisherConverter publisherConverter, SubPublisherConverter subPublisherConverter) {
        this.publisherService = publisherService;
        this.publisherConverter = publisherConverter;
        this.subPublisherConverter = subPublisherConverter;
    }

    @GetMapping
    public String newPublisher(Model model) {
        PublisherResource publisher = new PublisherResource();
        publisher.setStatus(true);
        return showPage(publisher, model);
    }

    protected String showPage(PublisherResource publisher, Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("publisherForm", publisher);
        return "/publishers/publishers-edit";
    }

    @PostMapping
    public String createPublisher(@ModelAttribute("publisherForm") @Validated PublisherResource resource, BindingResult result, Model model) {
        if(result.hasErrors()) {
            return showPage(resource, model);
        }
        return savePublisher(resource);
    }

    @GetMapping("/{id}")
    public String editPublisher(@PathVariable("id") Integer id, Model model) {
        Publisher publisher = publisherService.getPublisher(id);
        PublisherResource res = publisherConverter.convert(publisher);
        res.setSubPublishers(publisherService.getSubPublishers(publisher).stream().map(s->subPublisherConverter.convert(s)).collect(Collectors.toList()));
        return showPage(res, model);
    }

    protected String savePublisher(PublisherResource resource) {
        Publisher publisher = populatePublisher(resource);
        List<SubPublisher> subPublishers = populateSubPublishers(resource);
        if(resource.getId() == 0) {
            publisherService.createPublisher(publisher, subPublishers);
        } else {
            publisherService.updatePublisher(publisher, subPublishers);
        }
        return "redirect:/publishers";
    }

    protected Publisher populatePublisher(PublisherResource resource) {
        Publisher publisher;
        if(resource.getId() == 0) {
            publisher = new Publisher();
            publisher.setTimeAdded(new Date());
        } else {
            publisher = publisherService.getPublisher(resource.getId());
        }
        publisher.setPublisherName(resource.getPublisherName());
        publisher.setDescription(resource.getDescription());
        publisher.setStatus(resource.isStatus());
        publisher.setWebsiteURL(resource.getWebsiteURL());
        return publisher;
    }

    protected List<SubPublisher> populateSubPublishers(PublisherResource resource) {
        if(resource.getSubPublishers() != null) {
            return resource.getSubPublishers().stream().map(s->{
                SubPublisher subPublisher = new SubPublisher();
                subPublisher.setName(s.getName());
                return subPublisher;
            }).collect(Collectors.toList());
        }
        return Collections.emptyList();
    }

    @PostMapping(params = { "addRow" })
    public String addRow(final PublisherResource publisher, Model model) {
        publisher.getSubPublishers().add(new SubPublisher());
        return showPage(publisher, model);
    }

    @PostMapping(params = { "removeRow" })
    public String removeRow(final PublisherResource publisher, final HttpServletRequest req, Model model) {
        final Integer rowId = Integer.valueOf(req.getParameter("removeRow"));
        publisher.getSubPublishers().remove(rowId.intValue());
        return showPage(publisher, model);
    }
}
```

**PublishersController**

```
@MenuController(value = "/publishers", item = Item.Publishers)
public class PublishersController {

    private PublisherService publisherService;
    private PublisherConverter publisherConverter;

    public PublishersController(PublisherService publisherService, PublisherConverter publisherConverter) {
        this.publisherService = publisherService;
        this.publisherConverter = publisherConverter;
    }

    @GetMapping
    public String showPage() {
        return "publishers/publishers";
    }

    @PostMapping("/data")
    public @ResponseBody DataTableResponse<PublisherResource> getPublishers(@RequestBody DataTableRequest request) {
        return publisherConverter.convertResponse(publisherService.getPublishers(request));
    }

    @DeleteMapping("/{publisherIds}")
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT)
    public void deletePublishers(@PathVariable Integer[] publisherIds) {
        for (Integer publisherId: publisherIds) {
            publisherService.deletePublisher(publisherId);
        }
    }

    @PutMapping("/{publisherIds}/disable")
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.ACCEPTED)
    public void disablePublishers(@PathVariable Integer[] publisherIds) {
        changeStatus(publisherIds);
    }

    @PutMapping("/{publisherIds}/enable")
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.ACCEPTED)
    public void enablePublishers(@PathVariable Integer[] publisherIds) {
        changeStatus(publisherIds);
    }

    protected void changeStatus(Integer[] publisherIds) {
        for (Integer publisherId: publisherIds) {
            publisherService.updateStatus(publisherId);
        }
    }
}
```

**PublisherConverter**

```
@Component
public class PublisherConverter  implements ResourceConverter<Publisher, PublisherResource> {

    public PublisherResource convert(Publisher publisher) {

        PublisherResource resource = new PublisherResource();

        resource.setId(publisher.getId());
        resource.setPublisherName(publisher.getPublisherName());
        resource.setDescription(publisher.getDescription());
        resource.setStatus(publisher.isStatus());
        resource.setWebsiteURL(publisher.getWebsiteURL());

        return resource;
    }
}
```

**PublisherService**

```
@Service
public class PublisherService {

    private PublisherRepository publisherRepository;
    private SubPublisherRepository subPublisherRepository;


    public PublisherService(PublisherRepository publisherRepository, SubPublisherRepository subPublisherRepository) {
        this.publisherRepository = publisherRepository;
        this.subPublisherRepository = subPublisherRepository;
    }

    public DataTableResponse<Publisher> getPublishers(DataTableRequest request) {   

        return publisherRepository.findAll(request); 
    }

    @Transactional
    public Publisher getPublisher(int publisherId) {
        Publisher publisher = publisherRepository.findById(publisherId);        

        if(publisher != null){
            List<SubPublisher> subPublishers = subPublisherRepository.findByPublisher(publisher);
            //populateSubPublishers(subPublishers);

            subPublishers.stream().forEach(s -> {
                if(s.getId() == 0){
                    s.setPublisher(publisher);
                    subPublisherRepository.save(s);
                }
            });
        }

        if(publisher == null) {
            throw new NotFoundException("Publisher " + publisherId + " not found.");
        }

        return publisher;
    }

    private void populateSubPublishers(List<SubPublisher> subPublishers) {
        for(SubPublisher subPublisher : subPublishers){
            subPublishers.add(subPublisher);
            System.out.println(subPublisher.getName());
        }
    }

    @Transactional
    public Publisher createPublisher(Publisher publisher, List<SubPublisher> subPublishers) {

        publisher = publisherRepository.save(publisher);
        createSubPublisher(publisher, subPublishers);       

        return publisher;
    }

    private void createSubPublisher(Publisher publisher, List<SubPublisher> subPublishers) {
        populateSubPublishers(subPublishers);

        for(SubPublisher subPublisher : subPublishers){
            subPublisher.setPublisher(publisher);
            subPublisher.setName(subPublisher.getName());
        }
    }

    @Transactional
    public Publisher updatePublisher(Publisher publisher, List<SubPublisher> subPublishers) {

        publisher = publisherRepository.save(publisher);
        createSubPublishers(publisher, subPublishers);
        return publisher;
    }

    private void createSubPublishers(Publisher publisher, List<SubPublisher> subPublishers) {

        subPublisherRepository.deleteByPublisher(publisher);

        for (SubPublisher sp : subPublishers) {
            sp.setPublisher(publisher);
            sp = subPublisherRepository.save(sp);
        }
    }

    @Transactional
    public void updateStatus(int publisherId) {
        Publisher publisher = publisherRepository.findOne(publisherId);
        if(publisher != null && publisher.isStatus() != false){
            publisher.setStatus(false);
            publisherRepository.save(publisher);
        }
        else if(publisher != null && publisher.isStatus() != true ){
            publisher.setStatus(true);
            publisherRepository.save(publisher);
        }
    }

    @Transactional
    public void deletePublisher(int publisherId) {
        Publisher publisher = publisherRepository.findOne(publisherId);
        if (publisher != null) {
            publisherRepository.delete(publisher);
        }
    }

    public List<SubPublisher> getSubPublishers(Publisher publisher){
        return subPublisherRepository.findByPublisher(publisher);
    }
}
```

**SubPublisherConverter**

```
@Component
public class SubPublisherConverter implements ResourceConverter<SubPublisher, SubPublisherResource> {

    @Override
    public SubPublisherResource convert(SubPublisher subPublisher) {

        SubPublisherResource resource = new SubPublisherResource();
        resource.setName(subPublisher.getName());

        return resource;
    }
}
```

**Error**

```
java.util.ConcurrentModificationException: null
    at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.checkForComodification(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.next(Unknown Source)
    at publishers.PublisherService.populateSubPublishers(PublisherService.java:58)
    at publishers.PublisherService.createSubPublisher(PublisherService.java:74)
    at publishers.PublisherService.createPublisher(PublisherService.java:68)
```

Comment: if the arraylist is empty no input will be generated because the `th:each` does execute 0 times (meaning never). So everything inside of the the `th:each` loop wont be included. You only need to move the `<button type="submit" name="addRow">+</button>` out of the `th:each`. th each is just like a java foreach loop. if you loop over a empty collection with foreach the loop would also not be executed.

Comment: @TommySchmidt Thx for your reply, I've tried to move <button type="submit" name="addRow">+</button> out of the th:each, and when i go to add new publisher it show me + button but when i click on it it react like Save button and save form without adding fields for subpublishers

Comment: from what u posted i can not tell why. please include your `<form>` tag in your question.

Comment: and make sure to also include the `showPage` method. or at least the important parts of it.

Comment: @TommySchmidt I included <form> tag and controller

Comment: what is the url that the for is getting submittet to (when you click on the addRow button)

Comment: @TommySchmidt  "publishers/publishers-edit"

Comment: in order to invoke `addRow` (in your controller) it should be `publishers/publishers-edit/<the id of the publisher>`. so that's a problem

Comment: @TommySchmidt I forgot to add id, url have id of publisher that is edited, on the prevoius url it add id of publisher with PostMapping annotation '@PostMapping(value="/{publisherId}", params={"addRow"})'

Comment: so the url was `publishers/publishers-edit/1` or some other random number in the browser?

Comment: @TommySchmidt it's not random number, it show id of publisher that is selected for editing

Comment: can you try to debug your code and see if the addRow method in your controller is called

Comment: @TommySchmidt it is called if i edit publisher that have subpublishers entered(i manually put them in database for test), but if i try to add new publisher or edit publisher that don't have subpublisheres, then there is no input fields, and when i put button for add out of the th:each and click on that button then it react like save button

Comment: thats why i asked if the function is called with the button NOT inside the th:each. because i think it is not

Comment: @TommySchmidt do you have any idea how i can resolve this?

Comment: @TommySchmidt If i move + button out of th:each and in edit form click on it then it throw nullPointerException for this line publisher.getSubPublishers().add(new SubPublisherResource()); in controller(method addRow()), but click on it in form for adding new publisher doesn't call this method addRow

Comment: can you include the PublicherResource class pls

Comment: @TommySchmidt i've included PublisherResource class

Comment: change the PublisherResource class like this: replace `private List<SubPublisherResource> subPublishers;` with `private List<SubPublisherResource> subPublishers = new ArrayList<>();` and try again (with the button outside of the th:each

Comment: @TommySchmidt it works when i edit publisher that doesn't have any subpublishers, but when i add new publisher then this button still react like submit button

Comment: this one is tricky but it is caused by your code design. the addRow method in the controller is mapped by a publisherId. so it will only work when there is a publisherId specified in the url. for a new publisher however there is no id until your saved it to the database.

Comment: @TommySchmidt I thought that this is problem. Is it possible to have multiple PostMapping value so that it can work with publisherId and without it? Or do you have any other suggestion how to resolve this?

Comment: i will give you some details later as i am busy right now sorry

Comment: @TommySchmidt Ok, no problem. Thx for helping me

Comment: so there is a pretty simple way to fix your problem. basically you dont need the publisherId in your url after the first request anymore because it is bound to a hidden input field in your form already. thymeleaf is smart enough to assign all input values to the corresponding fields in the specified object given via `th:object` in the `form` tag. you can provide the url to that the form submits to by adding `th:action="<the url>"` refer to: http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/articles/standardurlsyntax.html#only-for-thhrefs

Comment: So the submit url of the form could be changed to: publishers/publishers-edit. meaning that all methods BUT the `editPublisher` method dont need the path variable anymore because the id field in the `PublisherResource` object is eigher null (if the publisher was created) or the id that was specified in the first place (if the publisher was edited). If you dont understand what i mean by that i will prepare an example based on your classes and the html above. However that could take some time as i am really busy atm... So dont mind me if it takes some time

Comment: @TommySchmidt I've added th:action="@{/publishers/publishers-edit}" to form tag and remove path variables but when i try to click on + button for new publisher i get error (Whitelabel error page - This app has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback) and if i try to edit publisher when i click on +/- button i get 404 error (page not found)

Comment: please update your code in the question

Comment: @TommySchmidt I've updated my question

Comment: you didnt remove the path variable in the controller

Comment: @TommySchmidt i thought that i only need to remove path variable from addRow and removeRow methods. If I remove path variable from other methods, then i don't know other way how to implement them without publisherId

Comment: the `PublisherResource` does include the publisherId. just add it to the controller method and call `.id` on the object to get the publisherId. However be warned that it may be null (if the publisher a new publisher)

Comment: @TommySchmidt Here is how i made it, but it throw me error when i run project (Parameter 0 of constructor in com.nth.mobileapptracking.publishers.PublisherController required a bean of type 'com.nth.mobileapptracking.resource.PublisherResource' that could not be found.) Can you pls write that code as answer

Comment: i will prepare the example and answer later

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So here is the example. Ofc you need to replace the mapping for the controller (`/test/test`) to `/publishers/publishers-edit`. Controller:

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.validation.BindingResult;
import org.springframework.validation.annotation.Validated;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/test/test")
public class PublisherController {
    private PublisherService publisherService;
    private PublisherConverter publisherConverter;
    private SubPublisherConverter subPublisherConverter;

    @Autowired
    public PublisherController(PublisherService publisherService, PublisherConverter publisherConverter, SubPublisherConverter subPublisherConverter) {
        this.publisherService = publisherService;
        this.publisherConverter = publisherConverter;
        this.subPublisherConverter = subPublisherConverter;
    }

    @GetMapping
    public String newPublisher(Model model) {
        PublisherResource publisher = new PublisherResource();
        publisher.setStatus(true);
        return showPage(publisher, model);
    }

    protected String showPage(PublisherResource publisher, Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("publisherForm", publisher);
        return "test/test";
    }

    @PostMapping
    public String createPublisher(@ModelAttribute("publisherForm") @Validated PublisherResource resource, BindingResult result, Model model) {
        if(result.hasErrors()) {
            return showPage(resource, model);
        }
        return savePublisher(resource);
    }

    @GetMapping("/{id}")
    public String editPublisher(@PathVariable("id") Integer id, Model model) {
        Publisher publisher = publisherService.getPublisher(id);
        PublisherResource res = publisherConverter.convert(publisher);
        res.setSubPublishers(publisherService.getSubPublishers(publisher).stream().map(s->subPublisherConverter.convert(s)).collect(Collectors.toList()));
        return showPage(res, model);
    }

    protected String savePublisher(PublisherResource resource) {
        Publisher publisher = populatePublisher(resource);
        List<SubPublisher> subPublishers = populateSubPublishers(resource);
        if(resource.getId() == 0) {
            publisherService.createPublisher(publisher, subPublishers);
        } else {
            publisherService.updatePublisher(publisher, subPublishers);
        }
        return "redirect:/publishers";
    }

    protected Publisher populatePublisher(PublisherResource resource) {
        Publisher publisher;
        if(resource.getId() == 0) {
            publisher = new Publisher();
            publisher.setTimeAdded(new Date());
        } else {
            publisher = publisherService.getPublisher(resource.getId());
        }
        publisher.setPublisherName(resource.getPublisherName());
        publisher.setDescription(resource.getDescription());
        publisher.setStatus(resource.isStatus());
        publisher.setWebsiteURL(resource.getWebsiteURL());
        return publisher;
    }

    protected List<SubPublisher> populateSubPublishers(PublisherResource resource) {
        if(resource.getSubPublishers() != null) {
            return resource.getSubPublishers().stream().map(s->{
                SubPublisher subPublisher = new SubPublisher();
                subPublisher.setName(s.getName());
                return subPublisher;
            }).collect(Collectors.toList());
        }
        return Collections.emptyList();
    }

    @PostMapping(params = { "addRow" })
    public String addRow(@ModelAttribute("publisherForm") final PublisherResource publisher, Model model) {
        publisher.getSubPublishers().add(new SubPublisher());
        return showPage(publisher, model);
    }

    @PostMapping(params = { "removeRow" })
    public String removeRow(@ModelAttribute("publisherForm") final PublisherResource publisher, final HttpServletRequest req, Model model) {
        final Integer rowId = Integer.valueOf(req.getParameter("removeRow"));
        publisher.getSubPublishers().remove(rowId.intValue());
        return showPage(publisher, model);
    }
}
```

**Update**

I cleaned up your PublisherService and splitted it into PublisherService and SubPublisherService. Those Services are prob. optional but i prefer to have another layer between the repository and my programm most of the time.

I also cleaned up the PublisherController. `savePublisher` changed a lot. It is documented tho.

The Publisher now also has a List containing all SubPublishers for the Publisher. Prev. you were fetching this via code. However JPA can do this for you.

PublisherController:

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.validation.BindingResult;
import org.springframework.validation.annotation.Validated;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/test/test")
public class PublisherController {
    private PublisherService publisherService;
    private SubPublisherService subPublisherService;

    @Autowired
    public PublisherController(PublisherService publisherService, SubPublisherService subPublisherService) {
        this.publisherService = publisherService;
        this.subPublisherService = subPublisherService;
    }

    private ModelAndView showPage(PublisherResource publisher) {
        final ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("test/test");
        modelAndView.addObject("publisherForm", publisher);
        return modelAndView;
    }

    @GetMapping
    public ModelAndView createPublisher() {
        PublisherResource publisher = new PublisherResource();
        publisher.setStatus(true);
        return showPage(publisher);
    }

    @GetMapping("/{id}")
    public ModelAndView editPublisher(@PathVariable("id") Integer id) {
        Publisher publisher = publisherService.getPublisher(id);
        return showPage(PublisherConverter.convert(publisher));
    }

    @PostMapping
    public ModelAndView savePublisher(@ModelAttribute("publisherForm") @Validated PublisherResource resource, BindingResult result) {
        if(result.hasErrors()) {
            return showPage(resource);
        }
        return savePublisher(resource);
    }

    private ModelAndView savePublisher(PublisherResource resource) {
        // create the publisher
        Publisher publisher;
        if(resource.getId() == 0) {
            publisher = new Publisher();
            publisher.setTimeAdded(new Date());
            publisher = publisherService.save(publisher);
        } else {
            publisher = publisherService.getPublisher(resource.getId());
        }

        /* -- this will update the SubPublishers -- */
        final List<SubPublisher> toDelete = publisher.getSubPublishers();
        final List<SubPublisher> toSave = new ArrayList<>();
        final Publisher forLambda = publisher;
        // first we will iterate over all the SubPublishers that where specified by the user (in the form)
        resource.getSubPublishers().forEach(name->{
            // we will then try to find any existing SubPublisher for the given name and publisher (to avoid duplicated database entries)
            final SubPublisher subPublisher = subPublisherService.getOrCreateSubPublisher(forLambda, name);
            // we will also save the SubPublisher reference for later
            toSave.add(subPublisher);
            // and then we will remove the SubPublisher that we just found from the List of SubPublishers from the original Publisher (that was stored in the db)
            toDelete.removeIf(s->subPublisher.getId() == s.getId());
        });
        // effectively it will leave us with a list (toDelete) that will include all SubPublishers that have to be deleted
        for(SubPublisher subPublisher : toDelete) {
            // and this is what we will to here
            subPublisherService.delete(subPublisher);
        }
        // after we cleaned up all unused references
        publisher.getSubPublishers().clear();
        // update the subPublisher list to contain all SubPublishers that where specified by the user input (the parsed ones)
        publisher.getSubPublishers().addAll(toSave);
        /* -- end -- */

        // update all remaining fields
        publisher.setPublisherName(resource.getPublisherName());
        publisher.setDescription(resource.getDescription());
        publisher.setStatus(resource.isStatus());
        publisher.setWebsiteURL(resource.getWebsiteURL());
        publisherService.save(publisher);
        return new ModelAndView("redirect:/test/list");
    }

    @PostMapping(params = { "addRow" })
    public ModelAndView addRow(@ModelAttribute("publisherForm") final PublisherResource publisher) {
        publisher.getSubPublishers().add("");
        return showPage(publisher);
    }

    @PostMapping(params = { "removeRow" })
    public ModelAndView removeRow(@ModelAttribute("publisherForm") final PublisherResource publisher, final HttpServletRequest req) {
        final Integer rowId = Integer.valueOf(req.getParameter("removeRow"));
        publisher.getSubPublishers().remove(rowId.intValue());
        return showPage(publisher);
    }
}
```

Publisher:

```
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

@Entity
@Table
public class Publisher {
    private int id;
    private String publisherName;
    private String description;
    private boolean status;
    private String websiteURL;
    private Date timeAdded;
    private List<SubPublisher> subPublishers = new ArrayList<>();

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Column
    public String getPublisherName() {
        return publisherName;
    }

    public void setPublisherName(String publisherName) {
        this.publisherName = publisherName;
    }

    @Column
    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    @Column
    public boolean isStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(boolean status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    @Column
    public String getWebsiteURL() {
        return websiteURL;
    }

    public void setWebsiteURL(String websiteURL) {
        this.websiteURL = websiteURL;
    }

    @Column
    public Date getTimeAdded() {
        return timeAdded;
    }

    public void setTimeAdded(Date timeAdded) {
        this.timeAdded = timeAdded;
    }


    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "publisher")
    public List<SubPublisher> getSubPublishers() {
        return subPublishers;
    }

    public void setSubPublishers(List<SubPublisher> subPublishers) {
        this.subPublishers = subPublishers;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Publisher{" + "id=" + id + ", publisherName='" + publisherName + '\'' + ", description='" + description + '\'' + ", status=" + status + ", websiteURL='" + websiteURL + '\'' + ", timeAdded=" + timeAdded + ", subPublishers=" + subPublishers + '}';
    }
}
```

PublisherResource:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class PublisherResource {
    private int id;
    private String publisherName;
    private String description;
    private boolean status;
    private String websiteURL;
    private List<String> subPublishers = new ArrayList<>();

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getPublisherName() {
        return publisherName;
    }

    public void setPublisherName(String publisherName) {
        this.publisherName = publisherName;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public boolean isStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(boolean status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    public String getWebsiteURL() {
        return websiteURL;
    }

    public void setWebsiteURL(String websiteURL) {
        this.websiteURL = websiteURL;
    }

    public List<String> getSubPublishers() {
        return subPublishers;
    }

    public void setSubPublishers(List<String> subPublishers) {
        this.subPublishers = subPublishers;
    }
}
```

PublisherService:

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
public class PublisherService {
    private PublisherRepository publisherRepository;

    @Autowired
    public void setPublisherRepository(PublisherRepository publisherRepository) {
        this.publisherRepository = publisherRepository;
    }

    public Publisher save(Publisher toSave) {
        return publisherRepository.save(toSave);
    }

    public void delete(Publisher toDelete) {
        publisherRepository.delete(toDelete);
    }

    public Publisher getPublisher(Integer id) {
        return publisherRepository.findOne(id);
    }

    public Iterable<Publisher> getAll() {
        return publisherRepository.findAll();
    }
}
```

PublisherRepository:

```
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;

public interface PublisherRepository extends CrudRepository<Publisher, Integer> {}
```

PublisherConverter:

```
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class PublisherConverter {
    public static PublisherResource convert(Publisher publisher) {
        PublisherResource resource = new PublisherResource();
        resource.setId(publisher.getId());
        resource.setPublisherName(publisher.getPublisherName());
        resource.setDescription(publisher.getDescription());
        resource.setStatus(publisher.isStatus());
        resource.setWebsiteURL(publisher.getWebsiteURL());
        resource.getSubPublishers().addAll(publisher.getSubPublishers().stream().map(SubPublisher::getName).collect(Collectors.toList()));
        return resource;
    }
}
```

SubPublisher:

```
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.OneToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table
public class SubPublisher {
    private int id;
    private Publisher publisher;
    private String name;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "publisherId")
    public Publisher getPublisher() {
        return publisher;
    }

    public void setPublisher(Publisher publisher) {
        this.publisher = publisher;
    }

    @Column
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

SubPublisherRepository:

```
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;

public interface SubPublisherRepository extends CrudRepository<SubPublisher, Integer> {
    SubPublisher findByPublisherAndAndName(Publisher publisher, String name);
}
```

SubPublisherService:

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
public class SubPublisherService {
    private SubPublisherRepository subPublisherRepository;

    @Autowired
    public void setSubPublisherRepository(SubPublisherRepository subPublisherRepository) {
        this.subPublisherRepository = subPublisherRepository;
    }

    public SubPublisher save(SubPublisher toSave) {
        return subPublisherRepository.save(toSave);
    }

    public void delete(SubPublisher toDelete) {
        subPublisherRepository.delete(toDelete);
    }

    /**
     * This method will either find any existing SubPublisher by the Name and the Publisher or create one if none existed.
     */
    public SubPublisher getOrCreateSubPublisher(Publisher publisher, String name) {
        SubPublisher subPublisher = subPublisherRepository.findByPublisherAndAndName(publisher, name);
        if(subPublisher == null) {
            subPublisher = new SubPublisher();
            subPublisher.setPublisher(publisher);
            subPublisher.setName(name);
            subPublisher = save(subPublisher);
        }
        return subPublisher;
    }

    public Iterable<SubPublisher> getAll() {
        return subPublisherRepository.findAll();
    }
}
```

In the html i changed `<input type="text" class="form-control" th:field="*{subPublishers[__${stat.index}__].name}" />` to `<input type="text" class="form-control" th:field="*{subPublishers[__${stat.index}__].}" />`

Comment: Thx for example. I've tried this but i still get this error Whitelabel Error Page - This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback. I've tried + button on page fornew publisher, +/- buttons on edit page but i'm getting this error on every page.  I've replaced the mapping to /publishers/publishers-edit. I will put the rest of my code so that you can see is everything else ok, because it is a bit odd code designe, but i need to work with all these files

Comment: @alonso05 can you show what you've got so far as an update in your question?

Comment: I've edited my question and put all code that i have

Comment: @alonso05 please note that if your request mapping for the controller is `@RequestMapping("/publisher")` you need to change the form action to use that url too. eg: `th:action="@{/publisher}"`

Comment: I've changed th:action and now i get 404 error (Page not found)

Comment: @alonso05 alright try to see my updated answer. i think i forgot to add something in the addRow and removeRow method signature. can you request the following url in your browser: `<server>/publisher` and tell me what u get?

Comment: For this url localhost:8080/publisher and also when edit with this url localhost:8080/publisher/{publisherId} a get 404 error(page not found)

Comment: according to your updated code above the request mapping for the controller is `@RequestMapping("/publisher")` is that true? just asking because there gotta be at least the form (for the get mapping)

Comment: Yes it's true, the request mapping is @RequestMapping("/publisher")

Comment: I run project again and now i get this error for addRow method when i click on + button java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
 The method add(SubPublisherResource) in the type List<SubPublisherResource> is not applicable for the arguments (SubPublisher)

Comment: i assumed that the PublisherResource would hold a list of SubPublishers but according to your code (that u posted later) it is of type SubPublisherResource. just replace `publisher.getSubPublishers().add(new SubPublisher());` with `publisher.getSubPublishers().add(new SubPublisherResource());`

Comment: I've replaced that and when i click on save button i've got error that i posted in my question. This only happend when i add new publisher, editing work without any problem

Comment: this is how i got it right now: https://im2.ezgif.com/tmp/ezgif-2-7c68cfba7b.gif. the error you got there is caused because you iterate over the list with foreach AND manipulate the list inside the foreach loop in line 58 in PublisherService. also if you think about that code in that function it makes no sense. you are iterating over the list just to add all element to the list again.

Comment: Buttons work good, the only problem is these errors when i want to save. Can you help me to resolve this with some example?

Comment: my question would be: what did u want to archive with that function?

Comment: I've got some example and wrote this code by that example so that have all functions to look similar, but it seems to complicate and also i didn't understood what exactly this function work. If you have some other way to do this saving publisher with subpublishers it would be great

Comment: i updated my answer. however i want to point out that the SubPublisher database object is far from perfect. also there is no validation for duplicated inputs at the moment. so be careful

Comment: Thx for help :)

Comment: Make sure to understand what i did. If you have questions just ask. And i cant say it enough: View Validation is missing in this example. I updated the post again to give some more details.

Comment: Hi Tommy, can you help me with this problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43514093/thymeleaf-doesnt-take-value-from-input