# Thymeleaf doesn't take value from input

Tags: thymeleaf

I have problem with saving value from nouislider.

Here is my code:

**html**

```
<form id="campaignForm" th:object="${campaignForm}" method="post" class="form-horizontal">
    <input type="hidden" th:field="*{id}" />
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Session lifespan (hours): </label>
            <div class="col-sm-7">
                <div id="basic_slider" th:field="*{sessionLifespan}">                                   
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-2">
                <input class="form-control" id="basic_slider_value" th:value="*{sessionLifespan}"/>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-6">  
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-sm-9 col-sm-offset-3">
                        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Save</button>                                                 
                        <a class="btn btn-white" th:href="@{/campaigns}">Cancel</a>                                                  
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
```

**js**

```
var basic_slider = document.getElementById('basic_slider');

noUiSlider.create(basic_slider, {
    start: 0,
    step: 1,
    behaviour: 'tap',
    connect: 'upper',
    range: {
       'min':  0,
       'max':  30
    }
});

var basicSliderValue = document.getElementById('basic_slider_value');

basic_slider.noUiSlider.on('update', function( values, handle ) {
    basicSliderValue.value = values[handle];
});

basicSliderValue.addEventListener('change', function(){
    basic_slider.noUiSlider.set(this.value);
});
```

**controller**

```
@GetMapping
    public String newCampaign(@RequestParam(value = "appId", required = false) Integer appId, Model model) {

        CampaignResource campaign = new CampaignResource();
        if (appId != null) {
            App app = appService.getApp(appId);
            AppResource res = appConverter.convert(app);
            campaign.setApp(res);
        }
        return showPage(campaign, model);
    }

    protected String showPage(CampaignResource campaign, Model model) {

        model.addAttribute("campaignForm", campaign);
        model.addAttribute("appList", campaignService.getApps());
        model.addAttribute("publisherList", campaignService.getPublishers());
        model.addAttribute("sourceList", campaignService.getSources());
        return "campaigns/campaign-edit";
    }


    @PostMapping
    public String createCampaign(@ModelAttribute("campaignForm") @Validated CampaignResource resource, BindingResult result, Model model) {
        if (result.hasErrors()) {
            return showPage(resource, model);
        }

        return saveCampaign(0, resource);
    }

    @GetMapping("/{campaignId}")
    public String editCampaign(@PathVariable int campaignId, Model model) {

        Campaign campaign = campaignService.getCampaign(campaignId);
        CampaignResource res = campaignConverter.convert(campaign);

        return showPage(res, model);
    }


    @PostMapping("/{campaignId}")
    public String updateCampaign(@PathVariable int campaignId, @ModelAttribute("campaignForm") @Validated CampaignResource resource, BindingResult result, Model model) {
        if (result.hasErrors()) {
            return showPage(resource, model);
        }
        return saveCampaign(campaignId, resource);
    }

    protected String saveCampaign(int campaignId, CampaignResource resource) {
        Campaign campaign = populateCampaign(campaignId, resource);
        int appId = getAppId(resource);
        int publisherId = getPublisherId(resource);
        int sourceId = getSourceId(resource);

        if (campaignId == 0) {
            campaignService.createCampaign(campaign, appId, publisherId, sourceId);
        } else {
            campaignService.updateCampaign(campaign, appId, publisherId, sourceId);
        }

        return "redirect:/campaigns";
    }

    protected Campaign populateCampaign(int campaignId, CampaignResource resource) {
        Campaign campaign = null;
        if (campaignId == 0) {
            campaign = new Campaign();
            campaign.setTimeAdded(new Date());
        } else {
            campaign = campaignService.getCampaign(campaignId);
        }

        campaign.setCampaignName(resource.getCampaignName());
        campaign.setDescription(resource.getDescription());
        campaign.setStatus(resource.isStatus() ? UserEnums.StatusCampaign.ACTIVE : UserEnums.StatusCampaign.INACTIVE);
        campaign.setSessionLifespan(resource.getSessionLifespan());

        return campaign;
    }
```

**service**

```
@Transactional
    public Campaign createCampaign(Campaign campaign, int appId, int publisherId, int sourceId) {

        App app = appRepository.findOne(appId);
        campaign.setApp(app);

        Publisher publisher = publisherRepository.findOne(publisherId);
        campaign.setPublisher(publisher);

        Source source = sourceRepository.findOne(sourceId);
        campaign.setSource(source);

        campaign = campaignRepository.save(campaign);
        return campaign;
    }

    @Transactional
    public Campaign updateCampaign(Campaign campaign, int appId, int publisherId, int sourceId) {

        campaign.setApp(appRepository.findOne(appId));
        campaign.setPublisher(publisherRepository.findOne(publisherId));
        campaign.setSource(sourceRepository.findOne(sourceId));
        campaign = campaignRepository.save(campaign);

        return campaign;
    }
```

**converter**

```
@Override
    public CampaignResource convert(Campaign campaign) {

        CampaignResource resource = new CampaignResource();

        resource.setId(campaign.getId());
        resource.setCampaignName(campaign.getCampaignName());
        resource.setDescription(campaign.getDescription());
        resource.setStatus(campaign.getStatus() == StatusCampaign.ACTIVE);
        resource.setSessionLifespan(campaign.getSessionLifespan());

        if(campaign.getApp() != null) {
            resource.setApp(appConverter.convert(campaign.getApp()));
        }

        if(campaign.getPublisher() != null) {
            resource.setPublisher(publisherConverter.convert(campaign.getPublisher()));
        }

        if(campaign.getSource() != null) {
            resource.setSource(sourceConverter.convert(campaign.getSource()));
        }

        return resource;
    }
```

**error**

```
org.springframework.validation.BeanPropertyBindingResult: 1 errors
Field error in object 'campaignForm' on field 'sessionLifespan': rejected value [7.00]; codes [typeMismatch.campaignForm.sessionLifespan,typeMismatch.sessionLifespan,typeMismatch.int,typeMismatch]; arguments [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes [campaignForm.sessionLifespan,sessionLifespan]; arguments []; default message [sessionLifespan]]; default message [Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'int' for property 'sessionLifespan'; nested exception is java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "7.00"]
```

When i move slider it change value in input field, but when i click on save button nothing happend. If i remove `th:field="*{sessionLifespan}"`from input tag then it save data from form and for sessionLifespan in database it save value 0.

Comment: If you want us to help you, you should include [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). You should include the `from` tag and the submit button as well as the controller method that handles the request.

Comment: @TommySchmidt i've updated my question

Comment: can you also show what `campaignConverter.convert` does. also what do you mean with: `when i click on save button nothing happend`. did the form submit the request or not?

Comment: could you try changing: `<div id="basic_slider" th:field="*{sessionLifespan}">                                   
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-2">
                <input class="form-control" id="basic_slider_value" th:value="*{sessionLifespan}"/>` to `<div id="basic_slider"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-2">
                <input type="hidden" class="form-control" id="basic_slider_value" th:field="*{sessionLifespan}"/>`

Comment: @TommySchmidt i've changed to this but when i click on save button it stay on form page for new campaign. If i put like it is in question then it saves but for sessionLifespan save 0 value in database

Comment: it prob. stays on the same page because the bindingresult has an error. you should debug your code to see if and what errors the bindingResult has.

Comment: @TommySchmidt i've updated question with error that bindingResult output. Could problem be with javascript and value that it returns in input field

Comment: the problem is the type of sessionLifespan. the value that is passed to the controller is a floating point number but thr field type is int.

Comment: @TommySchmidt can i convert float to int with javascript

Comment: you could do that for sure. the question is: what input do you want to receive from the slider? for example 0 to 10 with stepsize 1

Comment: @TommySchmidt yes, that stepsize is ok and i converted float to int with parseInt, but problem is that when i go to edit page the value for sessionlifespan is always 0 because in javascript start value for slider is 0. I don't know how in javascript set value from database as start value

Comment: use the input value (on page load) to set the start value in the script. i'm currently on ma mobile, so cant provide any code atm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To address the last problem, change your javascript code like this:

```
var basic_slider = document.getElementById('basic_slider');
var basicSliderValue = document.getElementById('basic_slider_value');

noUiSlider.create(basic_slider, {
    start: basicSliderValue.value,
    step: 1,
    behaviour: 'tap',
    connect: 'upper',
    range: {
       'min':  0,
       'max':  30
    }
});

basic_slider.noUiSlider.on('update', function( values, handle ) {
    basicSliderValue.value = values[handle];
});

basicSliderValue.addEventListener('change', function(){
    basic_slider.noUiSlider.set(this.value);
});
```

The above code will get the value from the field before creating the slider and set the initial value to it. Ofc you still need to use `parseInt` if you want it to be a int value.

As you may noticed the cause of that problem was pretty simple but still hard to find because you did not notice that there was an error during the validation of the model attribute. In order to prevent similar problems i suggest you to either log any `BindingResult` related errors or use the `th:errors` attribute to display them in the form. Both ways will not fix the problem itself, but they will provide the information to fix it. Make sure to check [this](https://spring.io/guides/gs/validating-form-input/) to learn more about `th:error` and Form validation in general.